# Group_concat and then Exploding it into an Array

Tags: php, mysql

I am group_concat a bunch of reviews from my db which turns it into something like this:

This is review 1, This is review 2

then I explode it into an array like:

```
$review = $row->review;
$row->review = explode(',', $review);
```

This works great until someone in there review adds a `,` then it obsoulvy no longer works. So is there a way to group_concat and put something besides a comma between them? Is there a better way of fixing this? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, don't use `GROUP_CONCAT`. Create a subtable containing the reviews and appropriate relationships that link each review to.. whatever entities you are dealing with.

If you already have it set up like this, and are just using `GROUP_CONCAT` to fetch multiple reviews into a single result set... then still don't use `GROUP_CONCAT`. Use a subquery.

Comment: Yeah I figured, ok I will just change it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome - If you are interested, I'd recommend this book (which taught me the evils of `GROUP_CONCAT` and friends): http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-MySQL-Database-Design-Optimization/dp/1590593324/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1333583845&sr=8-1

Comment: but group_concat can be so cool..... haha. I like to use it sometimes for a quick query when i need to grab a bunch of id's

Comment: @Ascherer: It certainly has its uses. Just not as a replacement for a table :)

Comment: @Jacinto: I think you'll like it. Side note: It actually does have a real cover. Not sure why Amazon only shows the manuscript cover

Comment: @SimpleCoder: do you know of a good book that dives into MVC. BTW got the book today and love it already 50 pages into it.

Comment: Glad you like the book. Unfortunately, I haven't been shopping for MVC books for a while now. The frameworks change so often. I'd recommend doing the tutorials for each of the major frameworks (Zend, CakePHP, Symfony, CodeIgniter, etc.) to see which one you like best.